# Using nested queries vs CTEs and performance impact

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've been using sql for a while, and would like to know whether and how it would make sense to convert a script containing a lot of CTE's into a regular nested script. I'm using:

```
WITH cte_account_pricelevelid 
     AS (SELECT a.accountid, 
                a.pricelevelid 
         FROM   companypricelist a 
                JOIN(SELECT accountid 
                     FROM   crm_accountbase 
                     WHERE  defaultpricelevelid IS NULL) b 
                  ON a.accountid = b.accountid), 
     totals 
     AS (SELECT a.accountid, 
                a.pricelevelid 
         FROM   companypricelist a 
                JOIN(SELECT accountid 
                     FROM   crm_accountbase 
                     WHERE  defaultpricelevelid IS NULL) b 
                  ON a.accountid = b.accountid), 
     totalsgrouped 
     AS (SELECT pricelevelid, 
                Count(*) counts 
         FROM   totals 
         GROUP  BY pricelevelid), 
     final 
     AS (SELECT cte.accountid, 
                cte.pricelevelid, 
                frequency.counts 
         FROM   cte_account_pricelevelid cte 
                CROSS JOIN totalsgrouped frequency 
         WHERE  cte.pricelevelid = frequency.pricelevelid), 
     mycolumns 
     AS (SELECT b.accountid, 
                b.pricelevelid, 
                b.counts 
         FROM   (SELECT accountid 
                 FROM   crm_accountbase 
                 WHERE  defaultpricelevelid IS NULL) a 
                JOIN final b 
                  ON a.accountid = b.accountid), 
     e 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY accountid 
                    ORDER BY counts, pricelevelid ) AS Recency 
         FROM   mycolumns), 
     cte_result 
     AS (SELECT accountid, 
                pricelevelid 
         FROM   e 
         WHERE  recency = 1) 

SELECT a.accountid, 
       a.defaultpricelevelid, 
       b.pricelevelid 
FROM   crm_accountbase a 
       JOIN cte_result b 
         ON a.accountid = b.accountid
```

I feel that it is silly to keep running the same query within my CTE's:

```
SELECT accountid 
                     FROM   crm_accountbase 
                     WHERE  defaultpricelevelid IS NULL
```

But I don't know how to get around it. I suppose that I can convert this into, but don't know if there would be any performance gain.

```
select * from (select * from(select * from(...
```

**Is there an opportunity to tremendously improve performance by converting this into a nested SQL or just simplifying the CTE? If so, would you kindly get me started?**

Comment: Zero gain.  CTE is just syntax.  The CTE is just plugged into the final query.

Comment: thanks! would you then say that it is usually cleaner to use CTE's the way I did? instead of having a bunch of select from( select from (select from ( select from...?

Comment: from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751253/do-i-need-a-recursive-cte-to-update-a-table-that-relies-on-itself#comment36520286_23751253 the user 861051069712110711711710997114 says that there is a performance issue with CTE's http://screencast.com/t/S22Pqjqqfvl   is this not correct?

Comment: Looks like the syntax could be improved but moving the cte into the query just to eliminate the cte will not make a difference.

Comment: thanks! in what way could it be simplified? could you give me an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If accountid is indexed this join will not use that index
The derived table has not index

```
SELECT a.accountid, a.pricelevelid 
  FROM companypricelist a 
  JOIN (SELECT accountid 
          FROM crm_accountbase 
                     WHERE  defaultpricelevelid IS NULL) b 
    ON a.accountid = b.accountid
```

This will use an index on accountid
Even if there is not an index on accountid it will be faster

```
SELECT a.accountid, a.pricelevelid 
  FROM companypricelist a 
  JOIN crm_accountbase  b 
    ON a.accountid = b.accountid 
   AND b.defaultpricelevelid IS NULL
```

Comment: very interesting!! using "and" this way is always faster than using "where" ??

Comment: And will never be slower than Where.  Did you read my answer?   The main factor is using the index on accountid.  Why do you have two identical CTE?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to simplify it a bit. Mind running it and letting me know the results?

```
WITH 
 totals 
 AS (SELECT a.accountid, 
            a.pricelevelid 
     FROM   companypricelist a 
            JOIN(SELECT accountid 
                 FROM   crm_accountbase 
                 WHERE  defaultpricelevelid IS NULL) b 
              ON a.accountid = b.accountid), 
 totalsgrouped 
 AS (SELECT pricelevelid, 
            Count(*) counts 
     FROM   totals 
     GROUP  BY pricelevelid), 
 final 
 AS (SELECT cte.accountid, 
            cte.pricelevelid, 
            frequency.counts 
     FROM   totals cte 
            CROSS JOIN totalsgrouped frequency 
     WHERE  cte.pricelevelid = frequency.pricelevelid), 
 mycolumns 
 AS (SELECT b.accountid, 
            b.pricelevelid, 
            b.counts 
     FROM   final b 
          JOIN totals a
              ON a.accountid = b.accountid), 
 e 
 AS (SELECT *, 
            Row_number() 
              OVER ( 
                partition BY accountid 
                ORDER BY counts, pricelevelid ) AS Recency 
     FROM   mycolumns) 

SELECT a.accountid, 
       a.defaultpricelevelid, 
       b.pricelevelid 
FROM   crm_accountbase a 
       JOIN e b 
         ON a.accountid = b.accountid 
WHERE b.recency = 1
```